# Are there post-1700 examples of large scale long term reductions in living standards?

Tags: economy, social-history

I am looking for examples where an old person could talk of the 'good old times' and these were objectively better than the current times. Large scale meaning it affected not just individuals or a group but, at least a large socially significant population of an entire region and long term means a scale of at least 50 years or so.

I believe this did happen between 1500 and 1650 in North and Central America. A significant proportion of the population died to infectious diseases from the Europeans, often well before the Europeans showed up in person. This lead to a general collapse of societies followed by significant reductions in living standards.

The fall of the Roman Empire, around 400 to 500 in Western Europe is probably another example.

Are there examples of this that happened after the industrial revolution?

It seems to me that since the industrial revolution the major catastrophes were either overcome relatively quickly (say WW II, by 1955 living standards in Europe were much higher than ever before) or were merely phases or slower growth (during the cold war, communist countries grew much slower than capitalist ones but living standards were still ever increasing).

Comment: I'm not sure the living standards in Eastern Germany were higher in 1955 than in 1939.

Comment: And America is also dubious. Collapse of societies at contact was only in limited parts of North America (don't know about further south). The tribes in the forests probably had exactly the same living standards in 1650 as in 1150 or whatever.

Comment: Not really sure how you define "recent" but the Mongol invasions in Central Asia and the Middle East caused apparently permanent reductions in the level of civilization. Going from that to living standards on the other hand might be complicated.

Comment: @TomasBy Maybe in 1955 East Germany was only at about the same level as in 1939, but over a 50 year scale, WW II was only a temporary dip. For the Americas see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_history_of_indigenous_peoples_of_the_Americas An event like that causes reductions in living standards. My tipping point for 'recent' was the industrial revolution. The Mongol invasions would be another older example.

Comment: That page does not talk about living standards. Maybe they got higher living standards when there was less competition for the land and the game animals. WW2 temporary dip, yes because of 1989. I think Communism in Eastern Europe (not Russia) might be the best example of what you seem to be asking for.

Comment: The scale of at least 50 years in my opinion is not compatible with a post industrial revolution world. There have been several cases of widespread reduction in living standards following various events, but they all lasted a much shorter time. The industrial economy travels at such a speed that economic losses are recovered in a much shorter time than pre-industrial economies.

Comment: @Viralk That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: How do you factor in the effect of colonialism on the colonized: the Congo pre, during & post King Leopold, the Maori of New Zealand, indigenous Australians & indigenous Americans, north, central & south, etc.?

Comment: As Viralk says 50 years is a very long time. I would go further and say that it is incompatible with sustained civilisation in general - unless the civ goes extinct, living standards usually dip but then stabilise/recover. There has been economic collapses that lasts on the scale of a decade though. For example, the ongoing crisis in Venezuela. Less dramatically, many countries in sub-Saharan Africa have experienced sustained decline in standards of living. Are those something that would fit what you're looking for?

Comment: North Korea post-1990 might be an example. Or Afghanistan between 1980 and 2001. Most communist countries had serious transformation problems after 1990, but I am not sure if there is anywhere where these problems still outweigh economic progress. Tajikistan might be a candidate but there seems to be considerable cash inflow from Afghanistan.

Comment: What about Paraguay after the triple alliance war?

Comment: There's also Argentina. In the early part of the 20th Century it was ranked very highly in terms of quality of life but slipped to low rankings by the mid to late 20th Century.

Comment: I suspect that African American's in the US south standard of living decreased from 1700 to 1853.  I suspect there was a 50 year decline in Jewish standard of living during the modern period.  Piketty's thesis is that for some segments of society, decline relative to the mean is normal. 50 years is 2 standard generations, which is kind of contrary to the argument you're making.

Comment: No timeto write an answer just now, but I think Nauru fits.

Comment: How do you define "living standards"?  This is pretty subjective: by my subjective standards, just about anywhere in the modern urbanized world has declined.

Comment: Venezuela has 95% in poverty now, Argentina is going the same way...

Comment: Why have you excluded classed analysis?

Comment: @SamuelRussell While I hope the Q will be refined somewhat to a narrower focus, I do not see that as 'excluded' directly here. To the contrary. If you want to post an A that does this kind of frame challenge, be quick, (4CVs) to broaden the scope as you see fit for this (as long as "entire region" gets a proper treatment within this).

Comment: I was too slow, but I did edit the question on the point of class.  Answers relating to the desynchronisation of post-1972 wages and productivity, or the soviet working class post 1945 in terms of relative rates of growth, or enclosure after 1770 are now viable if the question is opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be quite eurocentric and built on assumptions of development: if we reference  'after the industrial revolution' does that mean we want to exclude large parts of Africa, Asia or Pacific colonies for much of the last 300 years? Are small Pacific islands 'industrialised' even now?

If on the other hand we just set the start date globally at 1700 or 1800 then would [Rapa Nui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_Island#European_contact) count?

Similar but worse to first contact in America, where at least standards of living  generally increased for settlers but generally decreased for natives, while on the Easter Island it just went all downhill, almost completely for much more than 50 years. The first contacts disrupted the social fabric by bringing diseases, then taking people away into slavery, then church and 'modernisataion'/'westernisation':

> On Easter Island itself, by the early 1700s the peak population of approximately 12,000 that might have been attained in the fourteenth and fifteenth centuries had perhaps shrunk, because of possible starvation and malnutrition leading to sterility, to as few as 6,000 souls.
> <sub>— Steven Roger Fischer: "Island at the End of the World The Turbulent History of Easter Island", Reaktion Books: London, 2005.</sub>

Note that this was accompanied with the toppling of the famous Moais between just 1770 and 1774. The entire 19th century is then a series of downward events leading to the almost complete desctruction of that society:

> [Destruction of society and population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Easter_Island#Destruction_of_society_and_population)
> A series of devastating events killed almost the entire population of Easter Island in the 1860s.

> The period 1862–88 is the second most important in Easter Island’s history. In the first nine years, approximately 94 per cent of the population perished or emigrated – one of the Pacific’s greatest human losses.
>
> Only in 1862 did the island start to suffer a ‘relentless process of modernization by Western agencies’, which, as a result, transformed its culture and bioscape profoundly and fundamentally. The ‘Great Death’ of the 1860s had been only the final gasp of that living corpse that Easter Island’s ancient culture had already become.
> <sub>— Fischer</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The prime example in the recent times is communist countries where living standards of millions of people
deteriorated for decades. The proof of this is the mass starvations in Soviet Union
in 1921, 1932-33 and 1946 when millions of people died. Nothing on this scale happened in the Imperial Russia. Same applies to China and Cambodia/Kampuchea. I suppose that the living standards in many Eastern European countries also deteriorated with establishing of communist regimes, though this may not be so evident as in the cases of Soviet Union, China and Cambodia.

Ref. [Black Book of Communism](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674076087)

Comment: Maybe the reason is that a) the Soviet Union is was exactly one communist country and b) most communist countries in Europe experienced a substantial growth in living standards until 1980 or so (from a low baseline ofc, post-WWII)

Comment: You could also include Cuba

Comment: ["the Soviet Union experienced three major welfare crises in the first half of the twentieth century as it progressed towards sustained higher welfare in the second half of the twentieth century, and that the statistical record of this progression is remarkably good,"](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.eeh.2008.06.002) This 'A' is incorrect in most aspects it presents & it does not answer the question as posed: "long term"/"of at least 50 years or so.". None of the incidences listed here come anywhere close to meeting that requirement.

Comment: I could see the Soviet Union from around 1920 until 1950 as an example. I don't see what Eastern European countries post WW II have to do with it though and it spite of much slower growth than the capitalist countries, these countries did not experience a long term reduction in living standards.

Comment: Its hard to argue that 1920 to 1950 wasn't industrialisation though.  Otherwise we could talk about standard of living collapse in British workers during the long enclosure.  Particularly in terms of diet calories & nutrition, diet variety, intensity of work, forms of social welfare, entertainment, security from external force.  Everyone knows enclosures are nasty.

The other way we could play this is talk about decline as relativity rather than absolute, because absolute declines are meaningless in value-form societies.  Problem is western imperialism is the comparator, not the metropole.